# How can I customize a "DHCP All scopes and leases" script?

Tags: powershell, server, scope, dhcp

Good day everyone,

I would like to modify the script below.

```
$DHCPServers = Get-DhcpServerInDC
$R = @()
ForEach ($Server in $DHCPServers)
    { $S = $Server.DnsName
      $Scopes = Get-DhcpServerv4Scope –ComputerName $S
      ForEach ($Scope in $Scopes) 
        {
            $AllScopes = $Scope.ScopeID.IPAddressToString
            $Results = Get-DhcpServerv4Lease -ComputerName $S -ScopeId $AllScopes -AllLeases | Select-Object @{Name="DHCPServer"; Expression={$S}},ScopeId,IPAddress,AddressState,ClientId,ClientType,HostName,Description,DnsRegistration,DnsRR,LeaseExpiryTime,NapCapable,NapStatus,PolicyName,ProbationEnds,ServerIP,PSComputerName
            $R += $Results
        }
                    
    }
$R | Sort-Object -Property DHCPServer,ScopeId,IPAddress | Out-GridView
```

1. How can I add an extra column to the output that shows the "Scope Id **Name**" just after the ScopeId column?  Ex |DHCPServer|ScopeId|**ScopeIdName**|IPAddress|
2. When sorting by IP address, an IP such as 192.168.1.100 shows in the output before 192.168.1.19.  How can I have the Sort-Object command recognize that .100 comes after .19.  Most addresses ending in single or double digits are sorted properly.
3. This isn't necessary but if it is possible to shorten the Server DnsName that would be appriciated. Ex DC1.orginization.org to DC1

I tried adding an extra expression to the output so I could add the "ScopeIdName" column but received an error.  The expression I tried was....

```
@{Name="ScopeName"; Expression={$Scopes.Name}}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I was able to figure out step 2 for my sorting issue. 

Sort-Object -Property DHCPServer,ScopeId,{ [Version]$_.IPAddress.IPAddressToString } | Out-GridView -Title "All Scopes and Leases for All DHCP Servers"

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty much a shot in the dark, I don't have access to the cmdlets you're using for testing but might be able to help you accomplishing the 3 requirements.

```
$sortproperties = @(
    'DHCPServer'
    'ScopeId'
    # lexicographical sorting
    { '{0:D3}.{1:D3}.{2:D3}.{3:D3}' -f @($_.GetAddressBytes()) }
)

Get-DhcpServerInDC | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($scope in Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $_.DnsName) {
        $getDhcpServerv4LeaseSplat = @{
            ComputerName = $_.DnsName
            ScopeId      = $scope.ScopeID.IPAddressToString
            AllLeases    = $true
        }

        foreach($lease in Get-DhcpServerv4Lease @getDhcpServerv4LeaseSplat) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                # it is possible that `$_` already has a `.Name` property here
                # and splitting on `DnsName` might not be needed
                DHCPServer      = $_.DnsName.Split('.')[0]
                ScopeId         = $lease.ScopeId
                # Assuming `$scope` object has a `.Name` property:
                ScopeName       = $scope.Name
                # not sure if this is already an `ipaddress` instance or not,
                # using `-as` just in case (might not be needed):
                IPAddress       = $lease.IPAddress -as [ipaddress]
                AddressState    = $lease.AddressState
                ClientId        = $lease.ClientId
                ClientType      = $lease.ClientType
                HostName        = $lease.HostName
                Description     = $lease.Description
                DnsRegistration = $lease.DnsRegistration
                DnsRR           = $lease.DnsRR
                LeaseExpiryTime = $lease.LeaseExpiryTime
                NapCapable      = $lease.NapCapable
                NapStatus       = $lease.NapStatus
                PolicyName      = $lease.PolicyName
                ProbationEnds   = $lease.ProbationEnds
                ServerIP        = $lease.ServerIP
                PSComputerName  = $lease.PSComputerName
            }
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object $sortproperties | Out-GridView
```

Comment: Thanks for the script.  I ran it in ise and it received an error.  I removed the | Sort-Object $sortproperties and kept the | Out-Gridview and it worked without the sorting part.  I will play around with your script today but it did fulfill my request #1.  Thanks for that!

Comment: Here is where it failed

Sort-Object : Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'GetAddressBytes'.
At line:44 char:5
+ } | Sort-Object $sortproperties | Out-GridView
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidResult: (@{DHCPServer=os...SComputerName=}:PSObject) [Sort-Object], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionEvaluation,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.SortObjectCommand

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Santiago!  I was able to get the script to work with your help.

```
$sortproperties = @(
    'DHCPServer'
    'ScopeId'
    # lexicographical sorting
    { '{0:D3}.{1:D3}.{2:D3}.{3:D3}' -f @($_.GetAddressBytes()) }
)

Get-DhcpServerInDC | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($scope in Get-DhcpServerv4Scope -ComputerName $_.DnsName) {
        $getDhcpServerv4LeaseSplat = @{
            ComputerName = $_.DnsName
            ScopeId      = $scope.ScopeID.IPAddressToString
            AllLeases    = $true
        }

        foreach($lease in Get-DhcpServerv4Lease @getDhcpServerv4LeaseSplat) {
            [pscustomobject]@{
                # it is possible that `$_` already has a `.Name` property here
                # and splitting on `DnsName` might not be needed
                DHCPServer      = $_.DnsName.Split('.')[0]
                ScopeId         = $lease.ScopeId
                # Assuming `$scope` object has a `.Name` property:
                ScopeName       = $scope.Name
                # not sure if this is already an `ipaddress` instance or not,
                # using `-as` just in case (might not be needed):
                IPAddress       = $lease.IPAddress -as [ipaddress]
                AddressState    = $lease.AddressState
                ClientId        = $lease.ClientId
                ClientType      = $lease.ClientType
                HostName        = $lease.HostName
                Description     = $lease.Description
                DnsRegistration = $lease.DnsRegistration
                DnsRR           = $lease.DnsRR
                LeaseExpiryTime = $lease.LeaseExpiryTime
                NapCapable      = $lease.NapCapable
                NapStatus       = $lease.NapStatus
                PolicyName      = $lease.PolicyName
                ProbationEnds   = $lease.ProbationEnds
                ServerIP        = $lease.ServerIP
                PSComputerName  = $lease.PSComputerName
            }
        }
    }
} | Sort-Object -Property DHCPServer,ScopeId,{ [Version]$_.IPAddress.IPAddressToString } | Out-GridView -Title "All Scopes and Leases for All DHCP Servers"
```

Comment: You could improve this by explaining what was wrong and how you fixed it, so that we don't have to search through the other Answers and comments to try to figure out what you did.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).